# How to increase heap memory in android

Tags: android

I am getting a value from webservice. I am parsing the value and adding it to `arraylist` while adding array list.

I am getting out of memory error in arraylist. Can anybody tell how to avoid this?

I read that one way to avoid out of memory error using increase heap size, but I don't how to do this - Can anybody tell how to do? Is there anyother way to avoid out of memory error?

Comment: if this android:largeHeap="true" thing would work as documented this would be my solution, but strangely the application tag in Manifest file does not allow for. it might be a documentation error and a residual of ancient times.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a OutOfMemoryException when you just add a value to an ArrayList it's probably because you have a memory leak somewhere.
Use largeHeap="true" only if you exactly know what object take lot of memory and you can't avoid it.

Answer (score -2):

You might be having memory leaks in your application - You really shouldn't be having memory issues otherwise. Android sometimes also has issues with automatic garbage collection, so try placing System.gc() and seeing whether that helps

Comment: System.gc is **NOT** a magic wand. It's a VM hint. Solving memory leaks is the real solution.

Comment: memory leaks may not always be the problem. I am currently looking into increasing my heap memory as my application uses 80% of the heap allocated to me by the application. Leaving me less then a meg to work with.

Comment: That's why I used the word 'might'. And yes, if you have memory leaks, you could potentially run out of heap memory. I don't know what you're trying to say.